# Serialising Observables

Tags: javascript, c#, system.reactive, rxjs

I would like to serialise execution of functions returning an observable. I've somewhat managed to do this but it is not a very pragmatic solution. What would be a more reactive way to achieve the following?

```
import Rx from 'rx'

export default class Executor {

  constructor() {
    this.queue = []
    this.draining = false
  }

  run(fn) {
    return Rx.Observable.create(o => {
      this.queue.push(Rx.Observable.defer(() =>
       fn()
          .doOnNext((value) => o.onNext(value))
          .doOnError((err) => o.onError(err))
          .doOnCompleted(() => o.onCompleted())))

      async () => {
        if (this.draining) {
          return
        }

        this.draining = true

        while (this.queue.length > 0) {
          try {
            await this.queue.shift().toPromise()
          } catch(err) {
            // Do nothing...
          }
        }

        this.draining = false
      }()
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you specify what you are trying to achieve a bit more?

Comment: I want to execute observable functions serially, e.g. in a client <-> server communication the client is not allowed to send more messages until the entire active reply has finished.

Comment: Maybe [this one](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/controlled.md) will help?

Comment: This question poses a little bit of a contradiction. Rx is all about being 'reactive', responding to events as they happen. Whereas you are trying to only react to events in a particular order but ask 'what would be a more reactive way'.
That said I think this can be simplified with the flatmapwithmaxconcurrent operator
https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmapwithmaxconcurrent.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve but it sounds like you are after the [flatMapWithMaxConcurrent](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/flatmapwithmaxconcurrent.md) operator.

```js
import Rx from 'rx'

export default class Executor {

  constructor() {
    // Queue of: () => Observable
    this.queue = new Rx.Subject();
    this.queue
        .flatMapWithMaxConcurrent(1,
            fn => fn().catch(Rx.Observable.empty()) // Replace with proper error handling
        )
        .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
  }

  push(fn) {
    this.queue.onNext(fn);
  }
}
```